# How to load keys from files and encrypt string with a private key

Tags: c#, cryptography

I can generate, encrypt/decrypt strings by referring to many samples posted in the last decade.

What I really need to accomplish is to be able to:

1. **import private key from a "xxxx.key" key file and encrypt a string with the private key**.
2. And then, **extract the public key from a "xxxx.crt" certificate file and decrypt the cypher text**.

I have generated public/private keys as well as self-signed certificate and stored in files using openssl binaries.

There are zillion samples that show how to generate keys (not importing from a file) and encrypt via public key.

There is a similar question that was partially answered and is not complete in this thread: [How to encrypt a string with private key and decrypt with public key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828803/how-to-encrypt-a-string-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key)

I'll appreciate any support and sample code (preferably in C++/C#/VB.NET).

Comment: If you can understand German a little bit (or use Google Translate), I've written [a small article with code snippets on my website](https://entwicklergate.de/t/eine-datei-mit-einem-oeffentlichen-schluessel-zertifikat-verschluesseln-und-mit-einem-privaten-schluessel-zertifikat-entschluesseln/468?u=uwekeim) that does encrypt and decrypt files. Should be very easily adaptable for in-memory strings.

Comment: Ich verstehe ein bisschen Deutsch. Vielen Dank.

Comment: Thank you @Uwe Keim. Your arcticle was usefull but still need help. You encrypt file not 
 a string and also use public key for encryption. I need to encrypt a string using a private key.

Comment: To my knowledge, when doing [asymetic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), the encryption is _always_ done with the public key and the decryption is _always_ done with the private key. Everything else seems to be of no sense to me.

Comment: I understand the conflict. Here is the scenario: I distribute a public key to many. I create a cyphertext with my private key and send. All can decrypt my message via the public key I sent earlier. Theoratically, asymetric keys is the best fit for this job. The problem is I cannot load a private key from file, construct the RSACryptoProvider with the private key and do encryption.